# how can super refer to parent class object when we create a child class object?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

When we create a child object, single object is created of child class which uses parent class variables. this is my understanding. I have read on many places that super refer to parent class object but here only one single object is created which inherits its members from parent class.
Does a parent class object is implicitly created inside child one to which super refers to?.I dont exactly get how people have written and in which context that it refer to parent class object ? when only child class object is created singly.

Comment: A child-class object is a superset of a parent-class object, i.e. a child "has everything a parent would have". It is one and the same object.

Comment: What do you mean by "child object"?  Do you mean an instance of a class that extends another class?  When you create an instance of any class you are creating just one instance.  That instance will have the properties and methods of its class and it will inherit the properties and methods of any classes it extends.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look there for super meaning and use.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Basically, you can see any object as an onion with the inner peel being Object and the outer one your object's class, with all the super classes in between. Each peel comes with its own attributes, class (overloaded, overridden, or new) and constructors (same) but the whole thing is a single object, each peel only seeing toward the inner core (except for overriden methods that are called to their outmost overriding peel - i.e. a method implementation that does not exist yet at the the considered peel declaration : see https://pretagteam.com/question/calling-an-overridden-method-superclass-an-calls-overridden-method)

> 1. If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword super.

> 2. You can also use super to refer to a hidden field (although hiding fields is discouraged).

> 3. You can also use super(...) to invoke a specific superclass constructor (whether it is not public or need to be called with specific parameters)